# Getting bad request when I include content-length in Headers for karate request

Tags: http-post, karate, request-headers

**I am performing one karate POST request where "Content-Length" in headers is mandatory field, the request has Content-Length =  . when I pass it , the response looks something like  Content-Length header already present, http call failed. when I remove it response says bad request, I have validated in POST-MAN and without Content-Length =  its returning 400 error. Is there any work around on it.**